# Fetch some records from one table corresponding to the records from another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables: "Books" and "Users"

```
1   Physics
2   Mathe
3   History

Bill  1
Tom   2
Tom   3
Henry 1
Bill  2
```

I want to make an SQL query to become, for example for "Tom":

```
Mathe
History
```

How could I do this?

Comment: What do you have so far?  This looks like homework.

Comment: Doing homework in stackoverflow, huh

Answer (score 1):

```
select books.name
  from books
  join users
    on books.id = users.id
 where users.name = 'Tom'
```

Assumes the 2 number columns on your tables are called "id". Replace that part of the sql with the actual column name. I also assumed the person names are stored in a column named "name".

Comment: StackOverflow - the best place to get your homework done.

Comment: @MattBusche It is impossible to evaluate whether someone asks a question that he or she is doing as part of an academic course. Just because the question is a simple one does not necessarily mean he or she is doing homework. If all simple questions were just ignored on this site it would become far less useful.

Comment: Ten seconds of googling would have found the answer they needed. This was pretty obviously homework.

Comment: There are questions as equally simple asked on here on an almost continuous basis. That does not mean you have to criticize every single person asking such questions as ‘doing homework on SO’ or those answering the questions as facilitating others doing their homework on SO. We are not here to identify students or to ensure that students -- or anyone for that matter -- put forth any effort into solving their problem. If you don't want to help someone because they've put in what appears to be minimal effort, then don't.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i do not do my homework, it´s just a part of a little site for my home library for my friends. I am not a proffi, but i like to make a little IT improvements in my life. :)